# Puppeteer blocked at .newPage()

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, headless

I want to use Puppeteer to generate PDF.

My environnement dev

- WSL2 Debian Buster
- Node v12.18.1
- npm 7.5.4
- Puppeteer 8.0.0

I tried many tutorials on the web to do it.
But the code is blocked on `browser.newPage()`

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
console.log(await browser.version()); //HeadlessChrome/90.0.4427.0 
const page = await browser.newPage(); //after it does nothing
```

Here the debug (six last lines) :

```
  puppeteer:protocol:RECV ◀ {"id":4,"result":{"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966"}} +0ms
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966","method":"Page.enable","params":{},"id":5} +1ms
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966","method":"Page.getFrameTree","params":{},"id":6} +1ms
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966","method":"Target.setAutoAttach","params":{"autoAttach":true,"waitForDebuggerOnStart":false,"flatten":true},"id
":7} +0ms
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966","method":"Performance.enable","params":{},"id":8} +0ms
  puppeteer:protocol:SEND ► {"sessionId":"B3D2567E07203D4A096A495710466966","method":"Log.enable","params":{},"id":9} +0ms
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have fixed the issue of my case:

Use `dumpio: true` to display log of Puppeteer.
After that, I found the error with `libX11-xcb.so.1` and disabled the gpu.

```js
  browser = await chromium.launch({
      args: ["--disable-gpu"]
    });
```

---

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1543#issuecomment-349642975
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4761#issue-770834723

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 20.04, Node.js v14.16.0, NPM 6.14.11, Puppeteer 7.1.0) it managed to be resolved just by installing `sudo apt install libx11-xcb1`, no `--disable-gpu` was needed; btw thanks for mentioning `dumpio: true` - it's very helpful